# sort lines with nonuniform fields

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file that contains names like the following:

```
cup-1.5.1-1_d03.rpm
cup-1.5-2_d03.rpm
cup-1.5.1-2_d03.rpm
cup-1.5-3_d03.rpm
```

I know that `cup-1.5.1-2_d03.rpm` should be the latest version. Is there a way to sort it properly so that the output would look like,

```
cup-1.5-2_d03.rpm
cup-1.5-3_d03.rpm
cup-1.5.1-1_d03.rpm
cup-1.5.1-2_d03.rpm
```

I tried

```
$ grep -o -P '(?<=cup-)[0-9]+.[0-9]+.*[0-9]+(?=.*.rpm)' a.txt |  tr '.' ' ' | tr '-' ' ' | sort -k4
1 5 2_d03
1 5 3_d03
1 5 1 1_d03
1 5 1 2_d03
```

but not sure how can I achieve it for the entire string. I have yet another file that has a little different versioning, where the field would be `-k5`.

```
$ cat b.txt
dup-1.1.1-3_d03.rpm
dup-1.1.1.1-1_d03.rpm
dup-1.1.1-1_d03.rpm
```

Here, I would expect an output:

```
dup-1.1.1-1_d03.rpm
dup-1.1.1-3_d03.rpm
dup-1.1.1.1-1_d03.rpm
```

Is there a way to sort these two files programmatically without relying on `rpm` utility if at all possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sort -V` (version):

```
sort -V file
```

```
cup-1.5-2_d03.rpm
cup-1.5-3_d03.rpm
cup-1.5.1-1_d03.rpm
cup-1.5.1-2_d03.rpm
```